# Why does the output stream only get buffered when I use the sleep() function?

Tags: c, sleep

Considering the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("X");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is nothing, until the buffer gets overflowed and subsequently flushed automatically by the system.

Why does it then not get buffered in this situation?:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("X");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The sleep() function seems to have some hidden effect here.

I'm new to the concept of buffers, therefore any additional information or notes about my potential misconceptions are welcomed.

Comment: A single-step through a debugger may prove useful in both samples, but particularly the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is still buffered, but the overflowing of the buffer (and thereby the flushing) happens so often in the second example that it's impossible to notice it.

If you run this on a system much slower than todays modern gigahertz PC's, you will definitely notice a difference.

Comment: But what orders the first example not flush the buffer immediately anyway?

Comment: @Rasteril It *doesn't*. That's the point. *Both* buffer the data equally. The latter has no stall to hold the loop back from filling the buffer, then flushing and continuing on ad-infinitum. The former is stalled between each put with a sleep().

Comment: @WhozCraig That would mean I should see the output every second, but I don't see any output whatsoever. Why does it do this?

Comment: @Rasteril no, that means the buffer in the former is filled after N-seconds (N being the internal buffer size) because you're purposely stalling with each put, before you finally see a dump. The latter has no such time-constriction, so N is reached *very* quickly.

Comment: @WhozCraig So if I changed the buffer to something larger, I would see pauses in the latter example aswell?

Comment: @Rasteril Yes, if you made the buffer *very* large (remember that a modern PC will be able to fill the buffer many *many* times every second without a pause).